# rounded corners on UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uipageviewcontroller, ibooks

I was wondering if anyone was ever successful in changing the corners of an UIPageViewController (the fancy book turning animation of iBooks) to rounded corners?

I tried this but to no avail:

```
[self.notebookPages setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];
self.notebookPages.dataSource = self.pageModelController;
self.notebookPages.doubleSided = NO;
[self addChildViewController:self.notebookPages];

    // mask

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 332, 480)
                                                      byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                                            cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(15.f, 15.f)];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

self.notebookPages.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[self.notebookScrollNavigationController.notebook.pages addSubview:self.notebookPages.view];

self.notebookPages.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 332, 480);
[self.notebookPages didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This is all a bit hardcoded (which is obviously bad) but I was just trying to find out if rounded corners would work. However, I only get a non-rounded transparent corner:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set the `layer.cornerRadius` property of `UIView` of the `UIViewController` pages?

Comment: I just tried that, only effected the corners pre turn-animation.  I'm on iOS5 though.  Might be different in iOS6.

Comment: I guess that this effect is managed by OpenGL not Core Animation, I don't think is possible.

Comment: Probably you should create a new image with rounded corners using Quartz, but this should be' done before adding them to the page view controller

Comment: iOS framework puts in a shadow, so when you have any transparent areas on your pages, the shadow shows through. I played around with this for hours and never found a way to change this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this import:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now you can use cornerRadius:

```
self.notebookPages.view.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
```